# Java. Mejorar velocidad de iteracion

Tags: java, algoritmos, array

> Ejemplo
>
> Para `a = [2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2]`, la salida debería ser
>   `firstDuplicate(a) = 3`.
>
> Hay 2 duplicados: números `2` y `3`. La segunda ocurrencia del `3`
>   tiene un índice menor a la segunda ocurrencia del `2`, de modo que la
>   respuesta es `3`.
>
> Para `a = [2, 4, 3, 5, 1]`, la salida debería ser `firstDuplicate(a) = -1`.
>
> Entrada/Salida
>
> [tiempo límite] 3000ms (java) [entrada] `array.integer a`
>
> Restricciones garantizadas: `1 ≤ a.length ≤ 10^5`, `1 ≤ a[i] ≤ a.length`.
>
> [salida] `integer`
>
> El elemento en `a` que ocurre en el arreglo más de una vez y que tiene
>   el índice mínimo para su segunda ocurrencia. Si no existe ningún tal
>   elemento, devuelve `-1`.

El asunto no es encontrar los duplicados, sino en mejorar la velocidad de respuesta, ya que el sistema que prueba mis algoritmos, genera datos aleatorios con muchísimos registros, de tal forma, que si usas muchas lineas de código o el mismo no es optimo, sucede que te excedes del tiempo maximo de 3 seg cuando el codigo es probado en cada tarea aleatoria generada por el sistema. Me gustaria conocer como mejorar este codigo.

```
int firstDuplicate(int[] a) {
    int numero = -1; //coloco un valor por defecto
    int indice = 100000; //agrego un valor maximo
    int i = 0; // y un contador


    for(int valor : a){// recorro todos los valores del registro que pueden ser muchos
       if(i >= indice) break; // si el indice del numero es igual al valor de recorrido, termina el analisis.
       if( numero != a[i] ){ // solo si el vecino no es igual lo analizo

           for(int n=(i+1); n<a.length; n++){ // cada vez que analizon un valor, desde alli analizo el resto de los vecino para ver si hay duplicados
                  if(valor == a[n] && n < indice){ // si el valor esta duplicado pero el indice es menor al duplicado anterior. Entonces lo guardas.
                      indice = n;
                      numero = valor;
                      break;
                  }
            }
       } 

        i++;
    }

    return numero;
}
```

Para mas detalle pueden verlo en [CodeFight](https://codefights.com/)

Comment: ¿Hace falta la descripción en inglés? Yo la eliminaría. La traducción está bien, no creo que aporte nada diferente,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siendo que el problema no restringe la cantidad de memoria que usas, sino que la velocidad es de importancia primordial, aprovecharía esto para crear un arreglo `boolean` de talla `a.length` para ir marcando de forma muy eficiente los números que voy encontrando en el arreglo `a` (`flags[n-1] = true`).

Si al considerar un número `n` encuentro que ya lo he marcado en una iteración anterior (`if (flags[n-1])`), entonces sé que ese es el primer número duplicado. De lo contrario, si llego al final del bucle, quiere decir que no encontré duplicados, entonces devuelvo `-1`.

La velocidad debería ser óptima ya que

- Solo se necesita iterar el arreglo `a` una sola vez.
- Todos los accesos al arreglo `flags` son óptimos ya que se hacen directamente por el índice.
- No depende de una de las clases de conveniencia en la librería estándar (`HashSet` u otro) que tienden a crear muchos objetos, en particular debido a que necesitan convertir los tipos primitivos a objetos (ej.: `int --> Integer`).

Código:

```
int firstDuplicate(int[] a) {
    boolean[] flags = new boolean[a.length];

    for(int n : a) {
        if (flags[n-1]) return n;
        flags[n-1] = true;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Y, de paso, al determinar la talla del arreglo (`new boolean[a.length]`) y la forma de acceder el arreglo según el número (`flags[n-1]`), estoy tomando en cuenta las restricciones del problema:

> Restricciones garantizadas: `1 ≤ a.length ≤ 10^5`, `1 ≤ a[i] ≤ a.length`.

Comment: Muy buena idea. Porque el asunto es encontrar la primera ocurrencia de cualquier numero pero solo se toma la ocurrencia del numero que tenga el indice mas bajo entre todas las ocurrencias encontradas

Answer (score 2):

Una de las cosas que veo en el código que colocaste es que tienes un doble `for` lo cual hace que la complejidad del algoritmo sea de `n^2`, ahora el problema de acuerdo a lo que entiendo es decir cual es el número que aparece dublicado por primera vez, lo cual indica que si lo encuentras no deberias seguir buscando. Para esto nos podemos apoyar en estucturas de datos como el `Set` de forma que recorramos el arreglo original, lo volcamos sobre el `Set`y cada vez que vayamos a guardar un número preguntamos si existe, en caso afirmativo ese será el primer número duplicado, en caso que no exista se guarda.

```
int firstDuplicate(int[] a) {
  int salida = -1;
  Set<Integer> duplicados = new TreeSet();
  for(int n : a){
    if(duplicados.contains(n)){
      salida = n;
      break;
    }else{
      duplicados.add(n);
    }
  }
  return salida;
}
```

De esta forma obtienes:
1. Reducir la complejidad algorítmica al no recorrer el arreglo dos veces
2. No evaluas todos los elementos del arreglo, solo los requeridos

Comment: Buena respuesta. Reduce la complejidad, pero al decir que se recorre una sola vez, no estás considerando que las operaciones del TreeSet también agregan complejidad. De [Class TreeSet<E>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), "*This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains)*".

Comment: Si quisieras mejorarlo aún más, podrías olvidarte del `.contains()`. El método [TreeSet.add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add-E-) devuelve `false` si ya estaba el elemento. Podrías reducirlo a `for(int n : a){if(!duplicados.add(n)){return n}}`.

Comment: Gracias por complementar la respuesta @Mariano, si bien la lectura del TreeSet tiene complejidad `log(n)` la complejidad del algoritmo sería de `n*log(n)` y no de `n^2` que sería la tener un doble `for`. Y por la respuesta del `TreeSet.add()` genial, no me habia percatado.

Comment: Me distes una buena idea. Tienes razón en varios puntos que honestamente había olvidado. Es verdad que los métodos como TreeSet son mas eficientes así como los de java8. Pero como puse en la respuesta posterior, después de encontrar todas las ocurrencias solo se toma el numero que tenga el indice o posición mas bajo. Voy a probar con estas ideas.

Comment: @AndyC este método también toma la primera ocurrencia de una repetición. Es más eficiente en el uso de memoria que la respuesta de sstan, y menos eficiente en velocidad (`O(n*log(n))` vs. `O(n)`).

Comment: @Mariano: No estoy tan seguro que sea mas eficiente en memoria. El problema es que las colecciones de Java no son capaces de trabajar directamente con los tipos primitivos como `int`. De modo que a cada `Add`, hay una conversión de `int` a `Integer` (autoboxing) que resulta en un objeto mas en el heap (a menos que el numero <= 127, numeros en el cache de `Integer`). Si los genéricos de Java pudieran manejar los tipos primitvos como lo hace C# por ejemplo, entonces sería mucho mas eficiente con la memoria.

Comment: @sstan entiendo, hay casos en los que juega en contra el autoboxing. Apuntaba más bien al *teórico*, dónde ir creando una colección, populada con cada elemento recorrido usa menos memoria que un array de N elementos (con un N grande).